# Java addition subtraction with money

Tags: java, class, netbeans, static, addition

I am trying to add and subtract dollars and cents but I am having trouble with going over 100 cents and under 0 cents. My code works fine for adding anything until I need to convert 100 cents into a dollar. I'm having trouble putting my words into code, but I understand what needs to be done to convert cents into a dollar.

FYI this is for a class so that is why I have code for static method addition/subtraction and class method addition/subtraction

My code:

```
package moneyapp;

public class MoneyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Money money1=new Money(99,99);
        Money money6=new Money(100,00);
        Money money7=new Money(0,1);

        add(money1,money7);
        System.out.println("The sum of "+money1+" and "+money7+" is "+money1.add(money7));
        subtract(money6,money7);
        System.out.println("The difference of "+money6+" and "+money7+" is "+money6.subtract(money7));
    }

    static Money add(Money money, Money money2)
    {
        int adddollars=money.dollars+money2.dollars;
        int addcents=money.cents+money2.cents;
        Money addmoney=new Money(adddollars,addcents);
        System.out.println(addmoney.toString());
        return addmoney;
    }
    static Money subtract(Money money, Money money2)
    {
        int subtractdollars=money.dollars-money2.dollars;
        int subtractcents=money.cents-money2.cents;
        Money subtractmoney=new Money(subtractdollars,subtractcents);
        System.out.println(subtractmoney.toString());
        return subtractmoney;
    }
}
```

Class code:

```
package moneyapp;

public class Money
{
    int dollars;
    int cents;

    public Money()
    {
        dollars=0;
        cents=0;
    }

    public Money(int dollar, int cent)
    {
        dollars=dollar;
        cents=cent;
    }

    public Money(int dollar)
    {
        dollars=dollar;
        cents=00;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        if(cents<10)
        {
            return "$"+dollars+"."+"0"+cents;
        }
        else
        {
            return "$"+dollars+"."+cents;
        }
    }

    public int getDollars()
    {
        return dollars;
    }

    public int getCents()
    {
        return cents;
    }

    public void setDollars(int dollars)
    {
        this.dollars=dollars;
    }

    public void setCents(int cents)
    {
        this.cents=cents;
    }

    public Money add(Money other)
    {
        int dol=dollars+other.dollars;
        int cen=cents+other.cents;
        Money answer=new Money(dol,cen);
        return answer;
    }
    public Money subtract(Money other)
    {
        int dol=dollars-other.dollars;
        int cen=cents-other.cents;
        Money answer=new Money(dol,cen);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it were me I could consider not having both 

int dollars;
int cents;

And instead just have

int cents;
Then $10.55 would just be 1055 cents. That way doing arithmetic is simple. You can just use the usual arithmetic operators.

Comment: Dividing a number by 100 (/) can give you the exact dollar amount, while modding by 100 (%) will give you the number of cents left over.

Comment: Both these comments are right -- you want to use "scalar" math, keeping track using a value scaled such that it can hold all your sums. You then convert to the format you want on output using division and mod.

Comment: All three of the above comments are right, but remember that you might get negative values sometimes and using integer division and mod will display -$10.60 as -$11 and +40 cents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this instead:

```
public class Money {

    private int m;

    public Money(int m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public int getDollars() {
        return m / 100;
    }

    public int getCents() {
        return m % 100;
    }

    public int get() {
        return m;
    }

    public Money add(Money other) {
        return new Money(m + other.get());
    }

    public Money subtract(Money other) {
        return new Money(m - other.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best way. Clean and no redundant data storage (like one variable for each dollar and cent).

Answer (score 0):

I updated your money class to fix the problem.

**Money addition**

100 cents is 1 dollar, so you can initialize dollar as:

```
this.dollars = dollar+cent / 100;
```

The amount of cents is than equal to the remainder of the division by 100

```
this.cents = cents % 100
```

In this way, cents will always be between 0-99.

**Money subtraction**

While your amount of cents is lower than zero, you can borrow 100 cents by decreasing the amount of dollars.

**Updated Money Class**

```
public class Money {
    public final int dollars;
    public final int cents;

    public Money() {
        dollars = 0;
        cents = 0;
    }

    public Money(int dollar, int cent) {
        dollars = dollar + cent / 100;
        cents = cent % 100;
    }

    public Money(int dollar) {
        dollars = dollar;
        cents = 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("$%d.%02d", dollars, cents);
    }

    public Money add(Money other) {
        int dol = dollars + other.dollars;
        int cen = cents + other.cents;
        Money answer = new Money(dol, cen);
        return answer;
    }

    public Money subtract(Money other) {
        int dol = dollars - other.dollars;
        int cen = cents - other.cents;

        while (cents < 0) {
            --dol;
            cen += 100;
        }
        Money answer = new Money(dol, cen);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to hold a single value (the amount) in 2 separate variables, especially when the range of the values is limited. If you want to emphasize the two different meanings, offer getter methods like getCents() and perform the calculation inside the getter.

Comment: @f1sh that would indeed be the best solution. But I didn't want to mess up the OP's code completely ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would put an if statement saying that if cents are >= 100 then add to the dollars 
    static Money add(Money money, Money money2)
    {
        int adddollars=money.dollars+money2.dollars;
        int addcents=money.cents+money2.cents;

```
    if(addcents >= 100){
        adddollars++;
    }

    Money addmoney=new Money(adddollars,addcents);
    System.out.println(addmoney.toString());
    return addmoney;
}
```

As for your subtraction method i would put something like
    static Money subtract(Money money, Money money2)
    {
        int subtractdollars=money.dollars-money2.dollars;
        int subtractcents=money.cents-money2.cents;

```
    if(subtractcents < 0)
        money.dollars--;
    money.cents=money.cents + 100;
    subtractcents= money.cents-money2.cents;


    Money subtractmoney=new Money(subtractdollars,subtractcents);
    System.out.println(subtractmoney.toString());
    return subtractmoney;
}
```