# Count how long the floating point is

Tags: java, double

How can I count how long the floating point is?

e.g.

```
count(10.123); //result: 3
count(10); //result: 0
count(10.3771) //result: 4
```

I know how to count it when transforming to a string, but that isn't very efficient, is it?

Comment: You need to convert to a string.  Counting digits is meaningless on a float.  It only means something with its string representation (and only for a specific base)

Comment: Transforming it to a String is definitely the easiest way, and I'll wager dollars to donuts that you're not creating an important, performance critical application worth hundreds of thousands of dollars.

Comment: How long is decimal representation of one third (`1/3`)?

Comment: Converting to a String is the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: What do you expect `count(10.000)` to return?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080804/java-how-to-count-the-number-of-decimals-contained-in-a-double-value-that-repr

Comment: How many digits are after the decimal point depends on how much precision you specify when converting to a string (e.g. in `printf`).

Answer (score 1):

A `double` is always a specific length. It will only show the numbers need to obtain the accuracy.

ie. 10.3771 is the equivilant to 00000010.37710000 (not the exact number of 0's that are really there, I'm just trying to explain the concept).

In reality even this is inaccurate as a `double` is a 64 bit binary number

Converting it to `String` is your best bet and not an inefficient method.

Comment: Well, actually 10.3771 is stored as 10.3771000000000004348521542851813137531280517578125, which is the nearest double precision number to 10.3771.

Comment: @DavidWallace, really?  That number has more than fifty digits, but a double can not even represent twenty digits of precision.  Also, those are decimal digits, but a java double always is an IEEE _binary_ floating point number.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes, really.  Given any number, you can write it in binary or in decimal; so there's really no such thing as a "decimal number" or a "binary number".  A java `double` has 64 bits, which is just the right amount to store this particular number.

Comment: @DavidWallace Point is that it doesn't make sense to talk about "how it's actually stored" and continue to use base 10. Providing the base 2 representation would be less deceptive.

Comment: No, it's really good for someone to understand "how it's actually stored" so that they use `float`, `double` and `BigDecimal` appropriately.  If I wrote that number with a series of 0s and 1s, it wouldn't be clear that it's _not_ exactly 10.3771.

Comment: I agree that understanding floating point numbers is great. My disagreement lies in that by stating a large decimal number as "the true value", it ignores the fact that the underlying representation is binary (which *is* one of the reasons why floats aren't "exact") and also implies a high degree of precision (which doesn't exist). 1s and 0s may be confusing, but too bad, because it's the truth.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi IEEE 754 defines a mapping from the finite floating point numbers into the real numbers. The result always has an exact representation as a terminating decimal fraction.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You're right, but it doesn't support the argument. Sure, floats are a subset of reals, but please explain why 0.1f is not equal to the real number 0.1. It has something to do with binary, doesn't it? Also, it's not surprising that all floats have terminating decimal fractions, since 2 is a prime factor of 10. If the binary fractions terminate, then so must the same values in decimal. Still doesn't mean the decimal fractions are short or a good representation.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi There is a finite set of real numbers that can be exactly represented in an finite sized numeric format, including double. 0.1 is not one of them.